# How to run slave automatically when master is down in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, database

I have `master and slave` running on different port. But when I `close master` the `slave goes down` too. I understand why this is happening. I want that when master goes down the slave become a new master `without restarting the mongod with --master` option. And My `mongodb connection never got down`.

Answer (score 3):

You need use the replicaSet system instead of the Master/Slave system in MongoDB.

all documentation about Replicat Set is on MongoDB wiki : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets